# What is the difference between VertexDegree and DegreeCentrality?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The functions `VertexDegree` and `DegreeCentrality` seem to both return the vertex degrees of a graph.  Why do we have both?  Is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VertexDegree` takes into account all edges, including self-loops and multi-edges.

`DegreeCentrality` ignores multi-edges and self-loops. It is equivalent to `VertexDegree[SimpleGraph[g]]`.

This is despite the documentation explicitly stating that `DegreeCentrality` takes into account self-loops.  From the Background section:

> Degree centrality is a measure of the centrality of a node in a network and is defined as the number of edges (**including self-loops**) that lead into or out of the node.

---

Example:

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1 <-> 1, 2 <-> 3, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 5}];

VertexDegree[g]
(* {2, 1, 1, 2, 2} *)

DegreeCentrality[g]
(* {0, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

Comment: Is Wolfram aware of this documentation bug?

Comment: @Alan I wrote them at the same time as posting this. Let's see if will get fixed (graph stuff doesn't often get fixed anymore).